# Why must the determinant of a matrix with with integer entries be an integer?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Why must the determinant of a matrix with integer entries be an integer?

Note: I know what a determinant of a matrix is, not sure how to explain this question.

Is that because if the matrix is made with integers the determinant has to be an integer as well?

Comment: because it is a polynomial in terms of the entries.

Comment: Also mysterious at first glance: if a square matrix has integer entries and determinant equal to 1, why does its inverse also have integer entries?

Comment: You claim you know what a determinant is - but there are multiple possible definitions and under some of them, the answer to your question is obvious. I think you should state your preferred definition of the determinant.

Comment: It's not a polynomial 'in terms of' the entries - it's a polynomial *in* the entries.

Answer (score 19):

[One of the various formulas for the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n.C2.A0.C3.97.C2.A0n_matrices) of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is
$$\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n A_{i,\sigma_i} $$
where as usual $A_{i,j}$ denotes the entry of $A$ in the $i$th row and $j$th column, and $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)$ is either $+1$ or $-1$, depending on $\sigma$. Thus, if every $A_{i,j}$ is an integer, then $\det(A)$ is just a huge sum of products of integers, and is therefore an integer itself.

Comment: This says it all.

Answer (score 12):

This is precisely because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a *ring* - it is closed under addition and multiplication.  That is to say, any time you multiply two integers, you get an integer.  Any time you add two integers, you get an integer.  So if the entries of your matrix are all integers, the determinant is just a sum of products of integers.

Answer (score -1):

There is also an induction proof on all matrices whose entries are integers.

Induction hypothesis: All integer valued $n$ by $n$ matrices have integer determinants.

Let $M$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix.

$n = 1$: 
$\det M = m_{11}$ which is an integer.

$n = k$: 
From cofactor expansion:
$\det M = \sum_{i=1}^n m_{1i}(-1)^{i+1}\det(M^{'}_{ij})$

Where $a_{1i}$ is $i_{th}$ entry in the first row and $\det(M^{'}_{ij})$ is the $(n-1)$ by $(n-1)$ sub-matrix. We know the sub-matrix has also integer entries. So from hypothesis, $\det(M^{'}_{ij})$ is an integer.
Then, the term within the sum, $m_{1i}(-1)^{i+1}\det(M^{'}_{ij})$, is just a multiplication of integers and it is also an integer. Which concludes the whole sum is another integer value.

Look for details of cofactor expansion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion