# Why is the determinant of an integer matrix always an integer?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Why is the determinant of an integer matrix always an integer? I am using the definition of the determinant as being the product of the diagonal entries of a matrix in upper triangular form.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421313/why-must-the-determinant-of-a-matrix-with-with-integer-entries-be-an-integer)

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form

Comment: I don't think the suggested answers respond to the OP's question.  Apparently, he isn't allowed to use expansion by minors, or so I interpret it, anyway.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that multiplying a row of a matrix by $k$ multiplies the determinant by $k$?

Comment: "I am using the definition of the determinant as being the product of the diagonal entries of a matrix in upper triangular form". And someone calls this "linear algebra done right"...

Comment: As you see it depends on your definition of $\det$. If your integer matrix isn't upper triangular, how do you define its $\det$.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I am allowed to use that property

Comment: @reuns I am made to put it into "upper triangular form" by using elementary row operations.

Comment: @user1551 Not sure if you are referring to Axler's book, but I am currently working from Apostol's Calculus Vol 2.

Comment: Then show those row operations don't change $Vol(M[0,1]^n)$ the volume of the image of the unit cube by $M$, so that $|\det(M)| =|\det(T)| =Vol(T[0,1]^n)= Vol(M[0,1]^n)$ the latter being clearly an integer as it is the volume of a parallelepiped with integer vertices

Comment: @JohnArg Because this is basically how Axler defines determinant.

Comment: @JohnArg Are you sure you are reading the definition correctly? Apostol didn't define determinant using triangular matrix (although he did show that the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the diagonal entries). He defined the determinant as the unique alternating multilinear function such that $\det(I)=1$ (this is the definition used by many textbook authors). I also cannot find the said exercise in Apostol's Calculus vol. 2. Would you please cite the page number and question number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we try to reduce the matrix to upper triangular form, we encounter the problem that the element we are trying to eliminate may not be a multiple of the pivot.  We can deal with this by multiplying the row of that element by the pivot.  This multiplies the determinant by the pivot, but it also multiplies the diagonal element by the pivot.  Once we have reduced the matrix to triangular form, we can cancel the product of all the pivots from both sides.

I know I haven't expressed this very well, so let me do an example.

$$\begin{align}
D&=\begin{vmatrix}2&3&6\\4&1&2\\5&1&7\end{vmatrix}\\
D&=\begin{vmatrix}2&3&6\\0&-5&-10\\5&1&7\end{vmatrix}\tag{1}\\
2D&=\begin{vmatrix}2&3&6\\0&-5&-10\\10&2&14\end{vmatrix}\tag{2}\\
2D&=\begin{vmatrix}2&3&6\\0&-5&-10\\0&-13&-16\end{vmatrix}\\
10D&=\begin{vmatrix}2&3&6\\0&-5&-10\\0&-65&-80\end{vmatrix}\\
10D&=\begin{vmatrix}2&3&6\\0&-5&-10\\0&0&50\end{vmatrix}\\
10D&=2\cdot-5\cdot50=-500\\
D&=-50
\end{align}$$

In $(1)$, we can just subtract twice row $1$ from row $2$.  In $(2)$, we have the problem that $2\nmid5$, so we multiply row $3$ by $2$. The remainder is similar.

Comment: Could you explain how you got the bottom row from $(10,2,14)$ to $(0,-4,2)?$  $(10,2,14)-5(2,3,6)=(0,-13,-16)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I have no idea what I did.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The explicit definition of determinant only uses multiplication and addition (and subtraction); it does not use division. When you multiply/add integers, you get, again, integers.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid fractions by something similar to Euclid's algorithm.   Rather than make the numbers below a pivot be zero, subtract a multiple of the pivot row so that all numbers below the pivot are smaller than the pivot.  Then choose the smallest nonzero number in that column as the new pivot.  The procedure ends of course, with just the greatest common divisor of the original values in the pivot place.  Then you go onto the next column.

Comment: The is the [Hermite normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form)

Answer (score 1):

If every entry in the diagonal is an integer, let's say we have a $5$x$5$ upper-triangular matrix where the diagonal entries are $a,b,c, d,e $. The determinant of this matrix is $abcde$. A property of integers which you can probably use without proof is that two integers multiplied together is an integer. Because any product can be subdivided into smaller products, this shows that any product of integers will have to be an integer. Hence the determinant will be an integer.

---

If the matrix that we start with is not upper triangular, it is possible to make it upper triangular via row operations. It is possible for the result to have non-integer entries.

However, we can make a matrix upper triangular without getting $1$'s in the diagonal. i.e., we do not divide any rows by integers. Then the resuling marix will surely be an integer matrix. And the determinant will not be multiplied by anything other than integers ( multiplying a row by a number affect the value of the determinant), so the determinant will also be an integer.

Comment: This works for an integer upper triangular matrix. But what if we just have a regular matrix and we put it in upper triangular form? It seems to me that the diagonal entries do not necessarily remain integers.